# How to avoid "Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'" in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, character-encoding

I have uncovered an unexplained instance of the:

- "**Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'**"

Which only seems to occur when I use a stored `PROCEDURE`.  The *mystery* is that all strings are literals within the script and I had expected that they all possess the *same* collating sequence.  There are several questions on this, though none relate to this kind of problem that I can see (I've pasted a list below for or others who find this question).

The script uses a stored `procedure` to do a simple heading.  Here is the original '*design*':

```
 DELIMITER $$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE    new_script( IN  label   VARCHAR(50) )
 BEGIN
     set @SCRIPT_NAME=label;

     set @script_count:=@script_count+1;
     set @script_error_count:=0;

     set @sqlstmt := concat('select \'', @DASHES, '\' as \'', @SCRIPT_NAME, ': starting ...\'');

     PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstmt;
     EXECUTE stmt;    

     DROP PREPARE stmt; 
 END$$$  -- new_script
 DELIMITER ;
```

The `concat()` statement fails with:

- ERROR 1271 (HY000) at line 241 in file: 'd:\work\test.sql':
- Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'

However *WHEN* I make an assignment to: `@SCRIPT_NAME` outside the `procedure` and comment-out the line:

```
     --  set @SCRIPT_NAME=label;
```

as shown, everything works!  For example:

```
  set @SCRIPT_NAME='dummy_script.sql';

  call new_script( 'IGNORED dummy_script.sql' );
```

Output:

```
  +--------------------------------------------------+
  | dummy_script.sql: starting ...                   |
  +--------------------------------------------------+
  |   ---------------------------------------------- |
  +--------------------------------------------------+
```

As required.

After playing with this a bit, I believe the problem is with the assignment from the parameter: `label` to the script variable: `@SCRIPT_NAME`.

It appears that `label` uses a different collation.  The thing I'd like is how to call the procedure and NOT have this error.  I would prefer not to set the value of `@SCRIPT_NAME` outside the `new_script` procedure.

- Is there a method to specify the SQL-script's collating sequence?  (Something like an XML header).  That way I could tell MYSQL to use the same collation for *everything*.
- Is there a way to find the collating sequence the SQL-script itself is using?
- Can I control the collating sequence used in the stored procedure?
- And really, why does MYSQL do this?

Or perhaps you have a better approach than these ideas -- Please share?

---

***related***:

- [Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753608/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-concat)
- [Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat' from mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213061/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-concat-from-mysql)
- [MySQL concatenation and Illegal mix of collations error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801998/mysql-concatenation-and-illegal-mix-of-collations-error)
- ["Illegal mix of collations for operation 'concat'" appears after data base import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762989/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-concat-appears-after-data-base-impor)
- [error Illegal mix of collations for concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226089/error-illegal-mix-of-collations-for-concat)
- [#1271 - Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473296/1271-illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation-union)
- [Illegal mix of collations for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38738042/illegal-mix-of-collations-for-operation)

Comment: As a note (note related to your question), but the normal way to get a single quote in a SQL string is to double it up.  So:  `'select '''` rather than `'select \''`.

Comment: Yes, you can override strings one at a time

Comment: how about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27226815 or the manual page and search on the word collation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html or all the user comments on the page

Comment: Stored procs fix their collation and charset when they are compiled. If you connect to mysql using a different collation and pass a variable to your stored proc, then you get this error message. Either explicitly coerce all strings to have the same collation within your stored proc or make sure you connect to mysql using the same collation as set in the stored proc.

Comment: Yes sounds like the pathway to collation hell -- the same script works in the MySQL workbench, not in the command line client.  The best course it seems is to establish a character set for the script that matches your currently in-use schema.  I quickly looked at this, there could be 4 or 5 session settings to consider . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW PROCEDURE ...
```

You will see a character set / collation was established when you `CREATEd` the SP.  `DROP` the SP, `SET NAME ...;` and re-`CREATE` the SP.